# Running two while loops simultaneously

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
   while(1)
   {
       // some code
   }
   while(1)
   {
       // some code
   }
}
```

How to run two while loop simultaneously ? How parallel programming is implemented for this in windows ? I'm using mingw compiler .

Comment: If you want to run them in parallel, you will need to put them in different threads.

Comment: which version? `c11` includes high level threading header `threads.h`.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr The C11 thread API is not available on most operating systems and Windows' C compiler doesn't even support C11. I would advise against using it because of the poor support.

Comment: @FUZxxl op is using mingw and i suppose mingw is using gcc

Comment: Can someone give me an example code?

Comment: *Can someone give me an example code?* Not until you do some research to try to find it yourself. You've been given the information to use to research: threads.

Comment: you could read the man page for fork() and for pthread_create() and for pthread_exit() and for pthread_join().   There are plenty of examples on stackoverflow.com that are using threads.

Comment: i did some research. `libc` supports `threads.h` not so long ago: https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2015-06/msg00894.html . and gcc maintenance in mingw is half dead. to have it works, you may need to build it yourself. or, you can choose to move to linux and it's better for you, since MS is an infamous C standard sabotager.

Comment: sounds like XY to me - why do they have to run at the same time, what are you doing?

Comment: @pm100 I am sure it is XY, but you can still point to something to learn..

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr That's barely a month old. Expect to wait at least two years until this patch finds its way into mainstream Linux distributions if at all. And I want to see the Windows implementation for that API.

Answer (score -1):

You can use fork() system call. It will create two processes, both can have two separate while() loops.

```
int main()
{
     if(fork()) {
         while(1) {
            /* some code */
         }
     } else {
         while(1) {
            /* some code */
         }
     }
}
```

You can get more details for fork() through it's man page in Unix.
Cygwin has fully featured fork() on Windows.

Comment: I mentioned that its for windows , I guess fork() cannot be used in windows , is there anyway to implement using winapi?

Comment: when ever calling fork(), always check the returned pid_t value.  there are three possibilites.  1) fork() failed  2) parent process  3) child process.  This answer does not handle the failed case.

Comment: I thought he wanted the 2 blocks to run simultaneously? Won't this only run one or the other depending on the failure of the fork?

Comment: @Carcigenicate `fork` is returning the PID of the child in the parent or `0` in the child. It is the way to distinguish the two processes after fork.